# How to Test Controller Private Method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, ruby-on-rails-4

This is my private method of controller

```
 def query_url(query)
   client_queries_path(@client, query)
 end
```

and this is my **index.json.jbuilder** file that I use that method

```
json.array!(@queries) do |query|
  json.extract! query, :id, :url, :keywords, :exclusions
  json.url query_url(query, format: :json)
end
```

I want to write test cases for that - so How can I write ?

Thanks In Advance

Comment: generally you shouldn't write tests for private methods because you shouldn't be calling them outside of the module or class that they are in.  So you should either make it public and test it, or keep it private and use a wrapper method to call it externally

Comment: please give me example or code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using something like rspec you can call a private method with `controller.send`.  So in your case:

```
controller.send(:query_url, "whatever query you want to test")
```

Comment: if I want to test this - client_queries_path(@client, query) - then how can I ?

Comment: Test it's functionality or test it gets called?  If the latter, just stub it to return a value and test that controller.send(...) equals the stubbed value.